# Error with library android.support.design.widget

Tags: android, import, package, libraries, navigationview

the problem is that android studio does not recognize the library to be imported. in the "build" file i added the lines below, but nothing that I solved the problem.  the error says "android.support.design.widget" package not found

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
```

Comment: can you please show the complete gradle build file?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, now I put them the answer.

First we open the project folder and go to the following path "PROJECT FOLDER \ .idea \ libraries"

Now edit the file: "design_22_2_0.xml" and before "" we put the following lines of code:

```
<ANNOTATIONS>
  <root url="jar://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/design/22.2.0/annotations.zip!/"/>
</ANNOTATIONS>
```

now you can import the library "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView"